# Namespace not found error when trying to compile

Tags: c#, .net, mono

***Edit: Changing the class name or namespace name so that the namespace and class don't have the same name doesn't fix this issue.***

I have this super simple code:

Program.cs:

```
using System;
using CodeCleaner;

class Program
{

    private static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("DocTypeChecker instantiated");

        var codeCleaner = new CodeCleaner.CodeCleaner();
    }
}
```

CodeCleaner.cs:

```
using System;

namespace CodeCleaner
{
    public class CodeCleaner
    {

        public CodeCleaner()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("CodeCleaner instantiated");
        }

    }
}
```

This produces the following error when I try to compile when I run `$ csc Program.cs`:

> Program.cs(4,7): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'CodeCleaner' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?).

I'm definitely not missing a using directive for CodeCleaner, but what it means with `assembly reference` I have no idea. Other solutions on the web didn't help me in this case. Anyone know the issue here?

Comment: I think the issue is the same name for namespace and class name.

Comment: That is not the issue. I tried changing the namespace name to `NCodeCleaner` and the issue persists (it then says `namespace name 'NCodeCleaner' not found`), so same issue.

Comment: Is CodeCleaner in the same assembly as Program?  If not, then Program's assembly needs to reference the assembly which has CodeCleaner.

Comment: If namespace and class names are the same can cause trouble but not in this case that he uses fully with name space and class name together like : `new CodeCleaner.CodeCleaner()`

Comment: @Loring I have no idea I'm new to C#. There is a file called `ProjectName.AssemblyInfo.cs` which has a bunch of info in there, like `AssemblyFileVersionAttribute(1.0.0.0)` etc.

Comment: @erol_smsr What IDE are you using?

Comment: @Loring Visual Studio code. There's an example about this, but it's about installing a MySQL package using NuGet, which complicates things. I just need to get a namespace working that I have made myself, it's not a NuGet package or something.

Comment: just use the same namespace for your Program class

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Running `csc Program.cs` won't compile CodeCleaner.cs, so your assembly will be missing the CodeCleaner class and namespace. Using `csc Program.cs CodeCleaner.cs` should do the trick.

Comment: I will try this out and update accordingly. But let’s say I want to add more than 1 file, so let’s say I have 10 namespaces and classes, do I have to list all the namespace files I am using?

Comment: @erol_smsr No, you can use `csc *.cs` or `csc -recurse:*.cs` in case you need to compile sub-directories as well.

Comment: Thanks! I just found it in the .NET docs and saw your comment now. This fixed the issue :)